# $http is null when testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I wrote a test that mocks a request to server which should return an array. The problem is, that when i launch my test it gives me error:

> Cannot read property 'get' of null

and when i debug it is clear, that $http is null for some reason, but if i launch my code, it sends a request to server. Maybe my mystake is that i am using $http directly from controller, maybe i should use service for that and it would solve the problem? Anyway, my main question is why $http is null and what am i doing wrong?

Code in controller:

`$scope.getLastReview = () => {
    $http.get('/lastReview').success((reviewArray: any) => {
    $scope.reviewsToShow = reviewArray;
     });
    };`

My test:

```
var sut = createController();
scope.getLastReview();
httpBackend.expectGET("/lastReview").respond(200, reviewArray);
httpBackend.flush();
expect(reviewArray.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

beforeEach:

```
        inject(($injector, $rootScope, $controller) => {
        httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
        httpBackend.whenGET("/lastReview").respond(200, reviewArray);
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = (): lastReviewController => {
            return $controller(lastReviewController.controllerId, { "$scope": scope, "$http": null, '$resource': null, '$interval': $interval});
        };
    })
```

Comment: Can you show your before each ?

Comment: @BorisCharpentier added beforEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize $http with null in your before each, don't specify it or inject $http but if you pass null, well it will be null in your controller.

Comment: omg, it was such a stupid mistake :[ sorry for bothering you with this question and thanks alot :)